# Check if sum possible in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

Given an array of `N` nonnegative integers and a `target` sum, check if it is possible to obtain `target` by choosing some elements of the array and adding them up. (An element can be chosen multiple times).

I tried to come up with a brute force recursive solution. My idea is that for each element, we have 3 choices

1. Include the element and stay in the same index
2. Include the element and move to the next index
3. Exclude the element and move to the next index

Here's my C++ code

```cpp
bool checkSum(vector<int> &arr,int i, int n, int target)
{
    if(target==0)
        return true;
    if(i>=n or target<0)
        return false;

    return (checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target) or // don't include current value and move to next
            checkSum(arr, i, n, target-arr[i]) or // include current value 
            checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target-arr[i])); // include current value and move to next
}
```

This code seems to fail for some testcases

```
arr = [10,7,0,6,2,6] target = 11
```

I am not able to find out what is the bug.

Driver Code

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n, target;
    cin >> n >> target;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    if (checkSum(arr, 0, n, target))
        cout << "YES\n";
    else
        cout << "NO\n";

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I am not looking for Dynamic Programming solutions as I just want to make my basics right first. It would be nice if I can know what I am missing in this code.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Please show a [mre]

Comment: How about checking if (target % current sum == 0)

Comment: Define "fail". Does it come up with the right answer? Does it hang? Have you tried printing something in each call to `checkSum()` so that you can see what path through the array you're taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array has a non-positive number (such as zero) in it, your solution will never stop iterating.

Comment: Question says non negative numbers. You must be trying to say that it will loop infinitely in case of array element being 0 right?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan: zero is a non-positive number that will trigger this issue.

Comment: Ya I was just updating the comment.

Comment: Hmm he will have to skip 0 entirely in current solution

Comment: So is there anything here I can add/modify so that the zero case can be handled?

Comment: @Dev5: Simply never include the element if it is zero.

Comment: @BillLynch Okay Thanks.. I think I can check that condition before I make the last 2 recursive calls

Answer (score 3):

The second recursion is causing the function to recurse infinitely as when `arr[i] = 0`, `checkSum(arr, i, n, target)` will call `checkSum(arr, i, n, target-0)` which will run infinitely.

It is senseless to add `0` more than once, so the only change required is to avoid the second recursion when `arr[i] == 0`

```
bool checkSum(vector<int> &arr,int i, int n, int target)
{
    if(target==0)
        return true;
    if(i>=n or target<0)
        return false;

    return (checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target) or // don't include current value and move to next
            (arr[i] ? checkSum(arr, i, n, target-arr[i]) : false) or // include current value 
            checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target-arr[i])); // include current value and move to next
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @BillLynch, it seems the code fails when any value is 0. So I just added an extra condition and it seems to work now.

```cpp
bool checkSum(vector<int> &arr,int i, int n, int target)
{
    if(target==0)
        return true;
    if(i>=n or target<0)
        return false;
    
    return (checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target) or // don't include current value and move to next
            arr[i]!=0 and   // include only if non-zero value
            (checkSum(arr, i, n, target-arr[i]) or // include current value 
            checkSum(arr, i+1, n, target-arr[i]))); // include current value and move to next
}
```

Comment: Accept his answer so that this question can be closed